# How to style wp_nav_menu?

Tags: menus

I am trying to style WP menu but i get some issues. This is the orginal menu and not a custom one. (css is already done and working).

What I want is this:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
                        $defaults = array(
                            'theme_location'  => '',
                            'menu'            => '',
                            'container'       => 'div',
                            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                            'container_id'    => 'myNavbar',
                            'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
                            'menu_id'         => '',
                            'echo'            => true,
                            'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                            'before'          => '<li>',
                            'after'           => '</li>',
                            'link_before'     => '',
                            'link_after'      => '',
                            'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="nav navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
                            'depth'           => 0,
                            'walker'          => ''
                        );

                        wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

                        ?>
```

And this is what I get:

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav">
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-56"><a href="[URL]">Page 1</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-58"><a href="[URL]">Page 2</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-60"><a href="[URL]">Page 3</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="[URL]">Sample Page</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Why does the classes and ID's end up missplaced?

Comment: you aren't outputting a menu because you've not specified any menu to output. you're getting the fallback `wp_page_menu` you've specified in your args.

Comment: So what menu should I specify if I want to output the standard menu? :)

Comment: there is no standard menu, you have to [register the menus you want](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu).

Comment: Do you mean register_nav_menu() or register_nav_menus()? Whats the difference between those two?

Comment: yes. one is for registering a single menu, the other lets you register multiple menus at once.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, thanks :) If you write this as an answer instead as a comment I will mark your answer as "Correct"  :)